# Why is my SQL code not executing the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, executable, store

So the objective of this is to show security so this is being done under a guest user account. I gave access to the guest user to execute this code. However I keep getting a NUll error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column , table ; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated. The
>   'vc_AddUserLogin' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL,
>   which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

So I have already tried to `EXEC  vc_AddUserLogin 'The Doctor', 'Gallifrey'`

Here is the code for the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE vc_AddUserLogin(@userName varchar(20) , @loginFrom varchar(50)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userID int
    SELECT @userID = vc_UserID FROM vc_User
    WHERE UserName = @userName
    INSERT INTO vc_UserLogin (vc_UserID, LoginLocation)
    VALUES (@userID, @loginFrom)
    RETURN @@identity 
END
```

The expected result should be a updated userid and login. I am not looking for a answer just someone to point me in the right direction because I am lost. This should be easy and I am probably overthinking it.

Comment: What are all the  columns in `vc_UserLogin`? maybe there's more than those 2 columns and that extra column wont allow nulls.

Comment: Do you have user "The Doctor" in table "vc_User"?

Comment: Yes I have a 'The Doctor'  already in the table and thank you you helped me figure out what i did wrong. When I entered in The Doctor I entered it in as TheDoctor. I am kicking myself now it is always these dumb little errors I do. Okay Thank you for that it made me look it up Procedure is working now

Comment: Thanks for the help I am sorry for bothering you nice folks. Also thanks for that interesting answer. That will help in the future if there is not a username that matches the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not return values from a stored procedure, other than as status for the procedure.  Instead, use an `OUTPUT` argument.

I also recommend using an `OUTPUT` clause, as in:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE vc_AddUserLogin (
    @userName varchar(20) ,
    @loginFrom varchar(50),
    @id int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int);  
    INSERT INTO vc_UserLogin (vc_UserID, LoginLocation)
        OUTPUT id INTO @ids  -- "id" is the name of the id column in vc_UserLogin
        SELECT u.vc_UserId, @loginFrom
        FROM vc_users u
        WHERE u.UserName = @userName;

    SELECT @id = id
    FROM @ids;
END;
```

You then call this code as:

```
DECLARE @id int;

EXEC vc_AddUserLogin @userName, @loginFrom, @id OUTPUT;

SELECT @id;
```

This will return `NULL` if no users match `@userName`.

Comment: You guys are awesome and that is a great procedure to figure out if there is missing data in this case the username. We haven't been taught that yet so very neat. Thank you for the answer! Turns out I made another bad grammatical/spelling error and I just need to go back to typing school.